# Asp.Net MVC: Use model binders in an AuthorizeAttribute?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, session-variables

I've a session vars that indicates me in which context I'm. On this contexts will depends some authorization.

Currently, I've a session vars, and I check it in a custom AuthorizeAttribute. It works great.

But I discovered the "ModelBinder" way, which basically adds a layer between  between the access to the session and the use in controllers.

Is there a way to also use this ModelBinder in my AuthorizeAttribute?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to also use this ModelBinder in my AuthorizeAttribute?

No, the model binder is invoked after the authorize attribute [OnAuthorization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.onauthorization.aspx) method assuming of course this method has authorized the request. But if you are interested in retrieving request parameters you could use the `filtyerContext`:

```
var value = filterContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("someparam");
```